# Find the matrix X such as A . X is close to B

Tags: matrices, optimization, algorithms

Consider :

`A` an `m` by `n` matrix

`B` an  `m` by `1` matrix

`C` an  `n` by `1` matrix

[image]

(in this example `m=3` and `n=5`)

What is the best algorithm to find the `y` positive integer values (in the B matrix) such as the matrix `A x B` is the closest possible to `C`.

(The distance between two (m,1) matrices is the absolute difference between the sums of all elements of each matrix).

---EDIT----

I just realized that it's the same as optimizing an `m` variables function :

[image]

But the question remains, how to find such values.

Comment: So, according to your definition, the distance between $(100,200)$ and $(200,100)$ is $|300 - 300| = 0$? If not, please clarify.

Comment: $A$ is actually a $5 \times 3$ matrix, and $AB$ will be a $5\times1$ matrix, not the same dimensions as $C$.

Comment: exatly. A zero distance means that they have the same sum of elements (300 in your example)

Comment: @DavidK of course. fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: see bottom for a better answer.

You can write this problem as an [integer linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). The only aspect of this that may not be obvious is how to handle the absolute value, since it is not quite linear. Let the sum of the entries of desired vector be $c$ as in your example. Rather than minimizing

$|(\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j = 1}^n x_{ij} y_j) - c|$,

instead define some new variable $W$, and add constraints

$(\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j = 1}^n x_{ij} y_j) - c \leq W$,

$-((\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j = 1}^n x_{ij} y_j) - c) \leq W$,

then minimize $W$.

Unfortunately algorithms for solving integer programs, while very sophisticated, are still quite slow (i. e. not polynomial time). If you are willing to accept non-integer values for the $y_j$ entries, then it is simply a linear program, for which good algorithms are known (such as the Simplex algorithm).

If the instances you are looking to solve are not too large (on the order of 10s or perhaps 100s of integer variables), you may be able to solve them exactly with commercial integer program solvers. If the instances are larger than that, and you require integer solutions, you will probably have to settle for some approximation, and in general finding good approximations is not easy either. A standard technique that may be useful to you is to relax the constraint that the variables are integers, solve the linear program using an efficient algorithm (yielding a non-integer solution), then round the resulting values to integers. You may or may not be able to guarantee anything about the quality of the rounded solution, depending on the specifics of the problem.

It's also possible that by thinking hard about the problem you may uncover some structure that allows you to avoid using an integer program and solve it another way. This is the ideal scenario, but I can't think of anything off the top of my head.

**Edit**: Here is the insight that eluded me yesterday. Not only do we not care about the values of the individual entries of the vector $C$, the individual entries of the matrix $A$ don't matter either, only the sums of the columns. If we call the sums of the columns of $A$ $X_1, X_2, X_3$, then the sum of the entries of $AB$ is $X_1y_1 + X_2y_2 + X_3y_3$. So changing $y_i$ just scales the sum of a column of the matrix.

Then the question is just to find a linear combination of some numbers (the sums of the matrix columns) as close to the number $c$ as possible. Assuming the entries of the matrix are integers, we can do this as follows: use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to compute $g = \gcd(X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n)$  (this is the smallest value that can be expressed as a linear combination of the sums) and the coefficients of the linear combination that equals the gcd, then compare which of $\lceil \frac{c}{g} \rceil \cdot g$ and $\lfloor \frac{c}{g} \rfloor \cdot g$ is closer to $c$. Whichever is closer, multiply the coefficients from the extended Euclidean algorithm by $\lfloor \frac{c}{g} \rfloor$ or $\lceil \frac{c}{g} \rceil$ to get the final coefficients.

This is the closest possible solution, since the gcd must divide any linear combination of the column sums. This algorithm is not only optimal, but runs in time logarithmic in the the smallest sum of a column of $A$! So really a nice well-behaved problem was hiding there after all.

Comment: thank you very much. The rounding of non-integer solution seems a good approach to this problem given the types of data I need to handle. The quality of this approach seems to be affected by the variance of the data to be handled, which doesn't seem to be the case for my data.